# Camel Stored Procedure Component Syntax

Tags: stored-procedures, apache-camel

I am using camel stored procedure to call a procedure in our db. The call expression is like this:

```
<camel:to uri="sql-stored:check_data(VARCHAR ${headers.id1},VARCHAR ${headers.id1},OUT INTEGER ${headers.response})?dataSource=ds" />
```

And the procedure is this:

```
check_data
@id1 varchar(50),
@bid2 varchar(50),
@response int output
```

After a trial, the component threw this:

```
org.apache.camel.component.sql.stored.template.ast.ParseRuntimeException: org.apache.camel.component.sql.stored.template.generated.ParseException: Encountered " <SIMPLE_EXP_TOKEN> "${headers.response} "" at line 1, column 80.
Was expecting:
    <IDENTIFIER> ...
```

I have checked the syntax sample in camel website and it seems it is true but I could not found anything wrong with this definition. What am I missing?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot in the OUT parameter refer to a header using the ${header.xxx} syntax. The current implementation stores the output as a Map, where you can define the key in the map to use in plain text, eg OUT response.

We could consider adding a new feature to the Camel component so you can tell it to store the OUT in a header instead of the message body.

You are welcome to log a JIRA ticket in the issue tracker at: http://camel.apache.org/support.html